# BluetoothSerial cordova plugin echoing write

Tags: android, bluetooth, phonegap-plugins, obd-ii, elm327

I'm using BluetoothSerial to connect an Android phone to an ELM327 OBD dongle. I have used a Bluetooth chat app to confirm that the appropriate data is returned on sending PID command codes (like 010C, 0105, etc.).

However, while the bluetoothSerial plugin seemingly works fine to locate and connect to the dongle, when I send the command codes over to the dongle using bluetoothSerial.write, I just get the same command codes fed back to me from bluetoothSerial.subscribeRawData. I tried using bluetoothSerial.available to see if these match the sizes of the replies, and they do.

I have not been able to find any known issues like this, so I was wondering if anyone else might have encountered this, or know why it might be happening.

Comment: Are you sending a \r after each command?

Comment: Nnnnnnyaaaargh!

Yup, that's it.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I really thought the write method handled that. :-(

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comment(I created an answer, so it is searchable better for others with the same problem):

OBD-II requires you to send a Carriage Return after each request.

So instead of sending `010D` to get the speed, you need to send `010D\r`.

---

*If found, the next characters will be interpreted as an internal configuration or ‘AT’ command, **and will be executed upon receipt of a terminating carriage return character.***

---

Source: [ELM327 Documentation](http://www.elmelectronics.com/DSheets/ELM327DS.pdf)